# What is the meaning of this lemma?

Tags: calculus, limits

Reading my calculus notes I found this lemma:

Suppose that $\lim\limits_{x \to a} f(x)=l$ and that $g(x)=f(x)$ for $0<|x-a|<\delta_0$ (for some $\delta_0$). Then $\lim\limits_{x \to a} g(x)=l$

What exactly does this lemma mean? I'm having trouble understanding it.

Answer (score 7):

It says that if the limit of $f$ at $a$ is $\ell$, and $f$ and $g$ are identical in some interval $(a-\delta_0,a+\delta_0)$ around, then the limit of $g$ at $a$ is also $\ell$. Or in other words, if two functions are identical in some interval around $a$, they have the same limit at $a$. In particular, if one of them actually **has** a limit at $a$, so does the other, and the limits are the same.